# Rooting the Nexus 7 2nd gen 2013

Tags: rooting, nexus-7

How do I Root my Nexus 7 tablet.It's not straight out of the box I have quite a few app installed... Can I keep the apps and data already on the device ?

Comment: Try Nexus Root Toolkit which should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use a toolkit as the commenter above has said. They will only make you more clueless about the whole process, and it honestly isnt that hard to root a nexus manually anyways. There are basically 3 steps:

1. Unlock bootloader
2. Install custom recovery
3. Flash root binaries through custom recovery.

For more elaboration on these steps, read [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2382051).

Comment: What's different? have you actually used it? Its a Win GUI frontend that does what that XDA post does... designed for noobs ;)

Comment: All it does is run fastboot and adb ands behind a gui. Its designed for noobs, but then they'll never learn how to do things properly.